# A question in tensor product of the module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

[image]

In M.F.Atiyah's "Introduction to commutative algebra", proposition 3.7 said there's an isomorphism as in the picture. But its proof is rather concise. I don't know how to prove this proposition according to the proposition 3.5, as in the following.
[image]
I think proposition 3.5 just gave us an isomorphism between A-module, but in proposition 3.7, we need to prove an isomorphism between $S^{-1}A $ module. I don't know how to relate them. Thank you!

Comment: This is very canonical.